# How to cast by byte number, in C?

Tags: c, memory-management

I have this struct:

```
t_scene *scene
```

I cast it in void *

```
void *base = (void *)scene;
```

Manually move to a field (for some reasons, manually move it's necessary)

```
void *param = base + sizeof(int);
```

Now, i need to cast param in int * if i want to dereferencing it:

```
*(int *)param = 12;
```

I there a way to derefence by a byte value ?
Something like that:

```
*(sizeof(int)*)param = 12;
```

Thank in advance !

Comment: hum what? 1. Why are you casting to `void *`? That type is implicitly convertible from/to any object pointer type. 2. If you want to get a byte, why not use shift and masking instead of playing with dangerous code (if you dereference the object through an incompatible pointer type other than a pointer to character type, your code has undefined behavior.)

Comment: I'm not sure what you're trying to do `sizeof(int)` isn't a type, and `sizeof(int)*` certainly isn't. What specifically are you trying to modify?

Comment: "for some reasons, manually move it's necessary" Try your best to eliminate this necessity. Otherwise, you are in for writing lots of error-prone and poorly portable code that is extremely hard to maintain. For example, `base + sizeof(int)` does not necessarily give you the correct address.

Comment: @dasblinkenlight : Portability is not planned. To have the correct address, i've already force my compiler to pack my struct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are asking how you can access specific bytes in a structure.  Typecast the pointer to an array, then access it as an array.  For example:

```
unsigned char *byteArray = (unsigned char *)scene;
byteArray[4] = 12;  //sets the fifth byte (offsets start at 0) to 12.
```

Comment: No, this is not quite "perfect". It's bad practice, at best.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest that you use bit masking instead of playing with potential UB. For example, if `t_scene` is a 32-bit type:

```
uint8_t lower_byte = scene & 0xff;
...
uint8_t high_byte = (scene >> 24) & 0xff;
```

Comment: What did you mean by "UB" ?

Comment: @PanzerKadaver Undefined behavior. Just so that you know: the answer you accepted is not even close to "perfect". If the type was anything else but `char *` or `unsigned char *`, the program would invoke undefined behavior. **I strongly recommend you use bit operations** instead of aliasing through incompatible (a. k. a. "who-knows-what-they-actually-do") pointer types. It's very dangerous, and you will get used to the bad habit.